# Amazing issue: position: absolute is affected by the parent's overflow: hidden?

Tags: css

I found out an amzing case where the **position: absolute** element is hidden.
You can also see demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/leoaivy/rs3c1zeL/).

```css
.grand {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* transform: scale(1,1); */
}
.parent {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is: **.grand** is set overflow: hidden and **.parent** is set transform: rotate(0deg), which make the child hidden. Normally, the .child with **position: absolute;** is not afftected by its parent elements not set **position: relative**. So what is the reason? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Likely, it's the fact that `.parent` has a transform, which [makes it the containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering) for the absposed element the same way `position: relative` does.

Comment: but if we don't set the .grand property overflow: hidden, this effect wouldn't happen

Comment: @tailor.lee: Are you sure? .parent itself isn't overflowing .grand because it's controlling its own child's overflow, so not having overflow: hidden on .grand wouldn't make a difference. If you removed overflow: hidden from *both* .grand and .parent, *then* you would see the overflow.

Comment: I'm sure cause you can try the demo at https://jsfiddle.net/leoaivy/rs3c1zeL/ where I deleted the oveflow: hidden on .parent and this still works.

Comment: @tailor.lee: You commented out the overflow property on .parent in that fiddle. Like I said, you would see the overflow if you removed the property from *both* of those elements.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I need to set overflow: hidden on both of those elements and this is the problem.

Comment: Coud anyone help me please? @@